# Gulp template cache task inconsistently not working

Tags: gulp, browserify

I have a series of gulp tasks that I'm executing but for some reason the template-cache only sometimes added to my final js file.

My console looks fine - as in no tasks are completing too late or early:

```
[10:44:50] Starting 'styles'...
[10:44:50] Finished 'styles' after 7.66 ms
[10:44:50] Starting 'scripts'...
[10:44:50] Starting 'template-cache'...
[10:44:50] Finished 'template-cache' after 7.83 ms
[10:44:50] Finished 'scripts' after 58 ms
[10:44:50] Starting 'pack'...
[10:44:50] Starting 'jam'...
[10:44:50] Finished 'pack' after 681 ms
[10:44:50] Finished 'jam' after 614 ms
[10:44:50] Starting 'default'...
[10:44:50] Finished 'default' after 4.56 ╬╝s
```

Here's my template cache function

```
    function buildTemplateCache(module) {
  return {
    src: dir.src + '/' + module + '/**/*.html',
    dest: dir.tmp + '/' + module,
    options: {
      module: 'balances.' + module,
      moduleSystem: 'Browserify',
      root: dir.mapping + '/' + module,
      templateHeader: "primeTemplateCache; primeTemplateCache.inject = ['$templateCache']; function primeTemplateCache($templateCache) {",
      templateFooter: '}'
    }
  };
}
```

and here is the initial call:

```
gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'pack', 'jam']);
```

and here are the relevant gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('pack', ['scripts', 'template-cache'], function (callback) {
  webpack(config.webpack.packs, callback);
});
gulp.task('jam', ['scripts', 'template-cache'], function (callback) {
  var jams = config.webpack.packs.map(minifyPack);
  webpack(jams, callback);
});
gulp.task('template-cache', function () {
  return Q.all(config.templateCache.caches.map(function (cacheConfig) {
    return gulp
      .src(cacheConfig.src)
      .pipe(templateCache(cacheConfig.options))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(cacheConfig.dest));
  }));
});
```

Has anyone run into an issue like this before?  It seems to only add the templates sometimes and not others.  Everything else is there as expected 100% of the time.

I at first thought it was a caching or sync issue but after looking at the logs and trying to reproduce for a couple days I can't find a way to do it consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `gulp.src` returns a stream, not a promise. So, `Q.all` will always resolve during the next tick. I think instead of `Q.all`, you want something like `es.merge` from [event-stream](https://npmjs.org/package/event-stream) or `combiner.obj` from [stream-combiner2](https://npmjs.org/package/stream-combiner2).

```
var es = require('event-stream');
gulp.task('template-cache', function () {
  return es.merge(config.templateCache.caches.map(function (cacheConfig) {
    return gulp
      .src(cacheConfig.src)
      .pipe(templateCache(cacheConfig.options))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(cacheConfig.dest));
  }));
});
```

Comment: This looks to have worked, thank you! I suppose I could have also listened for the 'end' of the event for the stream and resolve a promise that way too but this way works just as well.  Appreciated!